# One azure-pipeline.yaml for staging and production

Tags: azure-devops, azure, azure-pipelines, branch

Currently I have two separate Azure DevOps Pipeline config files:

- `azure-pipelines-staging.yaml`
- `azure-pipelines-production.yaml`

Really the only differences in them are the:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master # or staging
```

And the directory where my k8s manifests are:

```
manifests: |
  $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/azure/prod/api.yaml

# or 

manifests: |
  $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/azure/staging/api.yaml
```

So ideally it would be something like:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - staging
...
manifests: |
  $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/azure/$(branch)/api.yaml
```

Not quite seeing how to get `$(branch)` name in there. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services):

```
Build.SourceBranch  

The branch of the triggering repo the build was queued for. Some examples:

 - Git repo branch: refs/heads/master 
 - Git repo pull request: refs/pull/1/merge 
 - TFVC repo branch: $/teamproject/main 
 - TFVC repo gated check-in: Gated_2016-06-06_05.20.51.4369;username@live.com 
 - TFVC repo shelveset build: myshelveset;username@live.com

When your pipeline is triggered by a tag: refs/tags/your-tag-name
When you use this variable in your build number format, the forward slash characters (/) are replaced with underscore characters _).

Note: In TFVC, if you are running a gated check-in build or manually building a shelveset, you cannot use this variable in your build number format.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your after the branch name, and your branches don't include "directories" (example: releases/my_release), then `Build.SourceBranchName` will you give you "The last path segment in the ref". So, if `Build.SourceBranch` is `refs/heads/master`, then Build.SourceBranch will be `master`.

Your YAML:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - staging
...
manifests: |
  $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/azure/${{ variables.Build.SourceBranchName }}/api.yaml
```